# PDF render as image in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to render an uploaded PDF as an image to the front end so that I can add functionalities to add annotations with html and javascript. How would i go about doing so in c#? Every time I try to open the PDF in the browser the Browser's PDF viewer opens it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert pdf to images cheap libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983905/convert-pdf-to-images-cheap-libraries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in control of the server, and presumably you are, just [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/).

It can extract images from PDFs. Install it on your server, and invoke it using:

```
/// <summary>
/// The command line arguments for generating a thumbnail
/// 
/// {0} is the input source path
/// {1} is the output destination folder path
/// {2} is the output horizontal resolution
/// {3} is the output vertical resolution
/// </summary>
private const string ThumbnailArguments = " -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -dJPEGQ=95 -sOutputFile=\"{1}\\%03d.jpg\" \"{0}\"";

// Build the command line arguments
var arguments = string.Format(ThumbnailArguments, inputPath, outputFolderPath, imageWidth, imageHeight);

// Create the process to generate the thumbnail
using (var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "C:\\gswin64c.exe",
        Arguments = arguments,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    }
})
{
    // Attempt to start the process
    if (!process.Start())
        return;

    // Wait for the process to finish
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

Just replace the variables and pathd to suit your environment.

You can find more details on each argument and command [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm)